# How to style angular web component with material

Tags: angular, angular-material, web-component

I have created a web component with angular and I would like to know what is the best way to use angular material making sure that the style is not overridden by those who will include the web component and vice versa.

I am evaluating shadow dom but in that case, I need to import material themes in every component inside my web component if I am right.
This web component will be included in other angular application with material and inside some WordPress site.

Comment: Looks like you fully understand what you can and can not do

Comment: Ok but material inside shadow dom does not work well, I see for example checkbox and select without some css